# Ionic 3 app stopped making network request

Tags: android, cordova, ionic3

I don't know why there is not possibility to make ajax call
I have removed node_modules then made : npm i
then I have deleted platforms/android

and made :  ionic cordova run android
the network is still not working (on device or simulator)

I have switched to the master branch which was untouched but still face the same problem

But it works fine on IOS and web

Answer (score 0):

I upgraded the sdk for Android to 29, starting from sdk 28, you have to add the property to AndroidManifest.xml file in the node Application this attribute:

android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"

because I was making ajax calls to http and not https url.

Comment: However, this method is insecure, I would recommend he enables SSL if he controls the host, or if it is a cdn, that he downloads and package it inside the app.

Comment: @BastienBastien I know I should do this, but there are some legacy things that will break if we migrate to https don't ask me why

Answer (score 0):

Android needs the whitelist plugin (cordova-plugin-whitelist) to make requests outside the app (to the internet), are you sure you have included it? Also I used to have a similar problem, where the plugin was in my config.xml, however, it was not detected when I added the platform android using cordova@9.0.0. The solution for me was to move the plugin tag somewhere else in the config.

Refer to this https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-whitelist/, to know how to use the plugin if you have any doubts.

Here the config to whitelist navigation to somewhere:
`<allow-navigation href="mywebsite.com/coolpage.php" />` and here the config to whitelist requests to somewhere: `<access origin="mywebsite.com/api.php" />`

You can check if the whitelist plugin is installed by checking the logs, when you add a platform by making sure you see `installing cordova-plugin-whitelist` and that no errors comes up.

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you for your input but I had already use the whitelist plugin, that didn't work. I had to add the attribute usesClearTextTraffic to true for the reason I mentionned in my own answer